# What is the place of `word associations' in the field of pragmatics?

Tags: pragmatics

Let me immediately start off with an example:

Consider a group of nomadic people that is sustained by fishing. Occasionally, members of the community will travel to the sedentary world, to a city, to sell their fish on a market in order to buy manifactured products with the gains.

Next, consider a group of settled people that live in a city.

Now, I suppose that the mental representation of the word 'city' would differ among these two peoples (i.e. the cognitive effect of uttering a sentence such as *Let's go to the city!* differs: following my example above, the nomadic group of people would associate the utterance with the intention to sell fish; while the settled group of people would rather associate a 'city' with 'home').

My question is as follows: is this matter for the field of pragmatics, and, if so, what is the place of such phenomena in this field? (And how does it relate to the distinction between semantics and pragmatics in this case? As a city could possibly be understood to be 'a place to sell fish' in the nomadic case; and 'a place to live' in the sedentary case; which comes close to semantic meaning, I suppose.)

I find it hard to bring structure into the field of pragmatics and therefore have a lot of trouble finding literature relevant to the problem of which I listed an example above (any possible recommendations in that direction would be very helpful as well).

I would assume that my example would fall into the basket of pragmatics as it involves some sort of context dependency (in this case, some sort of ethnological or sociological context). However, most studies seem to focus on 'speech acts' and things like that, which feels a bit awkward in the case of my example. It might be that I'm also just a bit lost in formally defining the problem above. I have the feeling that I might need to look towards *indexicality* for my answer, however, that still does not lessen the confusion with regard to the place of this problem in the field of pragmatics (/ semantics).

Kind regards,

Comment: More cultural than linguistic; ethnographic linguistics studies stuff like this. As for how people associate words and concepts internally, linguistics has almost nothing useful to say, since individual differences are so gigantic.

Comment: Thank you! The terns ethnolinguistics and ethnosemantics indeed opened up a whole body of relevant research I see now.

Comment: @jlawler I have almost non-stop read about the field of ethnosemantics/pragmatics. You've helped me a lot! Your comment is really interesting. Assuming that you are aware of Wierzbicka's work, especially on cultural keywords and the NSM framework, I wonder whether you asserted that words such as 'city' (as in my example) are actually NOT cultural keywords, and would therefore not even fall in "the realm of pragmatics"; but that they would be material for cognitive studies instead of linguistics, even though their perception is culturally conditioned and "measurable" through language use?

Comment: @jlawler And would that be a result of "ethnopragmatics" actually aiming to "explain language use through culture" instead of vice-versa (what I'm aiming for); or is that unrelated?

Comment: @jlawler I have also seen criticism on ethnopragmatics (within the NSM paradigm) that I interpreted as that 'the classical distinction between semantics and pragmatics is broken'. If I understood correctly, in NSM (or the explanation of cultural keywords) only very few concepts, universal "building stones", belong to semantics (i.e. "good", "bad") and all that is built from it (the "meaning" of words) is "pragmatics", and culturally dependant. Does my problem (of whether this even falls within pragmatics) arise because of this new take on the semantic/pragmatic distinction, or does it  anyway?

Comment: @jlawler But then I also wonder: if my goal is to "explain culture" through language-then, does it even matter? As far as I understood, ethnopragmatics grounds itself in that a speaker's world view is captured entirely by his language use (and vice-versa) - a kind of Humboldtian view which however assumes universal semantic concepts (and therefore limits a speaker not only to a mother tongue). Please correct me if I'm wrong. Then, the language relativity theories that it builds on inherently entail that any cognitive sensations (ie associations) are also conveyed by this language usage,right?

Comment: Now you need to find somebody to talk to about it; we can't accommodate you here, but in a field this small you should find the people whose work you admire and correspond with them. At the very least they can point you at interesting sources and new work. And conventions, which are easier to attend these days when they're all done on Zoom, and you get to hear the very latest results, presented to colleagues. I tend to agree with Dan Everett about language being one tool of many available to culture, which is vaster than even language.

Comment: [Although I also agree with Sapir](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/210.html), "Everything that we have so far seen to be true of language points to the fact that it is the most significant and colossal work that the human spirit has evolved -- nothing short of a finished form of expression for all communicable experience. This form may be endlessly varied by the individual without thereby losing its distinctive contours; and it is constantly reshaping itself as is all art. Language is the most massive and inclusive art we know, a mountainous and anonymous work of unconscious generations."